# Get first and lastname from current user in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How do I get the first and last name of the current user in sharepoint?
My guess is to use the UserProfile property but i cant get it to work. Do i need a nugetpackage for that? But i dont have internet connection from my virutal machine so i cant do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the clientcontext for your site and add the following code 
       `

```
Group _managerGroupName=null; 
    if (clientContext != null)
                        {
                            var siteColl = clientContext.Site;
                            var web = siteColl.RootWeb;
                            GroupCollection groupColl = web.SiteGroups;`

                            clientContext.Load(siteColl);
                            clientContext.Load(web);




                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 


    _managerGroupName = web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
                                clientContext.Load(_managerGroupName);
                                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                  
    UserCollection managerGroupUsers = _managerGroupName.Users;
            clientContext.Load(managerGroupUsers);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            string[] Username = null;
            foreach (User u in managerGroupUsers)
            {
                Username = u.Title.Split(' ');
                string firstName = Username[0];
                string LastName = Username[1];

            }
```

Comment: declare a new variable `ClientContext clientContext=new ClientContext("<your sites url>");`

Comment: replace <your sites url> with the url of your site

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UserCollection or User variable. Then you can split the Title text by " ". This will help you get the First Name, LastName as well as MiddleName.

```
   UserCollection managerGroupUsers = _managerGroupName.Users;                         
                        clientContext.Load(managerGroupUsers);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        string[] Username=null;
                        foreach (User u in managerGroupUsers)
                        {
                             Username= u.Title.Split(' ');
                            string firstName = Username[0];
                            string LastName = Username[1];

                        }
```

Comment: UserCollection,  _managerGroupName and clientContext dont seem to work for me do i have to download nuget or add a using?

Comment: You need to add a dll named  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client. I will have the User and the UserCollection class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from your pastebin you're making a new server side web part. So you don't need Microsoft.SharePoint.Client. The previous examples are done with client object model, but you're using server object model. Replace the contents ot your onStart() function with this:

```
SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
string[] nameSegments = currentUser.Name.Split(' ');
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>First Name: " + nameSegments[0]));
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>Last Name: " + nameSegments[1]));
```

Comment: I got it to work but i dont want the display name I want the first/last name. So my display name is Administrator, my first name is Patrik last name Larsson and i want to get them not the display name. https://gyazo.com/2130018c2447ce251fc4333fbd8fdc3e